# Ajax data not sending, but requesting file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, get, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to build a chat system using ajax with xhttprequest. I request the file, the file responds, but the get data does not reach to it. I tried sending them even with post, but still, data does not reach the php file.
Here is the function that requests the file:

```
    function refreshChat(){
  if(username != ""){

    var date = new Date();
    var timezone_offset = date.getTimezoneOffset();

    $(".messages-container").empty();

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            $(".messages-container").html(this.responseText);
       }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "/chat/ajax_requests/get_messages.php", true);
    xhttp.send("receiver="+username+"&sender="+chat_with+"&limit="+limit+"&timezone_offset_minutes="+timezone_offset);
  }
}
```

And the requested file has this:

```
  $receiver = $_GET['receiver'];
  $sender = $_GET['sender'];
  $limit = $_GET['limit'];
  $timezone_offset_minutes  = $_GET['timezone_offset_minutes'];
```

What is wrong?

Comment: your php code does not print or echo anything

Comment: I am echoing the values with no result, but I didn't write in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found this on w3schools:
send(string): Sends the request to the server. Used for POST requests
send(): Sends the request to the server. Used for GET requests

I would recommend you to add the string from the send function to the url like this:

```
xhttp.open("GET", "/chat/ajax_requests/get_messages.php?"+"receiver="+username+"&sender="+chat_with+"&limit="+limit+"&timezone_offset_minutes="+timezone_offset, true);
xhttp.send();
```

then you are using the send function for a get request.

Link to Doc: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp